# Can Windows totally stop a thread if it's sleeping too often?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, tbb

I have a rare heisenbug in a multi-threaded application where the main thread, and only this thread, will just do nothing. As it's an heisenbug it's really hard to understand why this is happening.

The main thread is basically just looping. In the loop, it check several concurrent priority queues which contain tasks ordered by time to be executed. It pop a task, see if it's time to execute it. If it's time, it will just schedule it into TBB's task scheduler (using a root task which is the parent of all other tasks). If it's not time, the task is pushed again in the priority queue.
That's for one cycle. At the end of the cycle, the main thread is put to sleep for a very short time that I expect will be longer in practice but it's not really a problem, I just don't want it to use too much resources when not necessary.

Litterally:

```
    static const auto TIME_SCHEDULED_TASKS_SPAWN_FREQUENCY = microseconds(250);


    while( !m_task_scheduler.is_exiting() ) // check if the application should exit
    {
        m_clock_scheduler.spawn_realtime_tasks(); // here we spawn tasks if it's time 
        this_thread::sleep_for( TIME_SCHEDULED_TASKS_SPAWN_FREQUENCY );
    }

    m_clock_scheduler.clear_tasks();
    m_root_task.wait_for_all();
```

I have a special task that just log a "TICK" message each second. It is automatically rescheduling until the end of the program. However, when the heisenbug appear, I can see the "TICK" disappearing and the application not doing anything else than the work that occurs in non-main threads. So it appear that only the main thread is touched.

The problem can come from different places, maybe in the scheduling logic, but then it's also the only thread that have a sleep call. That sleep is a boost::this_thread::sleep_for().

My question is: **Is it possible that Windows (7 64bit) consider the main thread to be sleeping often and decide that it should sleep for a longer period of time than asked or be definitely ended?**

I expect that it is not possible but I would like to be sure. I didn't find any precision on this in online documentation so far.

---

Update:

I have a friend who can reproduce the bug systematically (on Windows Vista, Core 2 Duo). I sent him a version without sleep and another with the main loop reimplemented using condition_variable so that each time a task is pushed in the queue the condition_variable awaken the main thread (but still have a minimum time of spawning).

The version without sleep works (but is slower) - so the problem seem to be related even if I don't know the real source.

The version using condition_variable works - which would indicate that it's the sleep call that don't work correctly?

So, apparently I fixed the bug, but I still don't know why the specific sleep call can sometime block.

---

UPDATE:

It was actually a bug triggered by Boost code. I hunted the bug and reported it and it have been fixed. I didn't check the previous versions but it is fixed in Boost 1.55

Comment: Can't you break into the process with a debugger and see where the thread is waiting? I'd say that it's waiting for a lock that some other thread failed to release.

Comment: Do all threads have the same priority, or can it be that it simply sleeps longer as expected because other thread with a higher priority eat up the processing time?

Comment: @avakar Unfortunately as it's a rare heisenbug I can't reproduce it easily so I wasn't able to do this for now. Also, I have seen this bug more often in release mode than debug but it appear also in debug so...

Comment: @ogni42 I never touch thread priority because it's like invoking evil in your program and allowing the armies of chaos to be unleashed in it.  That being said, there is two other threads running, one I launch myself using boost::thread, the other launched by a library (RakNet) which I don't know what it does exactly. Maybe there is a problem there but then it shouldn't affect the main thread?

Comment: @Klaim, if the problem should reoccur, note that you don't need development tools on the production machine. You can create a dump of the process using e.g. Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), then open the dump on the development machine (as long as you still have the .pdb files).

Comment: I assume that this is a console or service app?

Comment: Also, you could find a way to get rid of the continual polling.  Sleep() loops are no substitute for effective inter-thread signaling:)

Comment: @MartinJames Nope it's client/server app, the problem appear either on the client or the server or both, as they share the exact same main loop code. However, the client have one threads running for graphic rendering (it's a 3D game). Both have a network thread to receive loop managed by RakNet (I asked on their forum if their thread can affect mine).
It's not "continual polling": the other threads only sometime push tasks that should not be executed immediately. The main thread is not waiting for a "signal", there is other systems for that. It's just dispatching tasks.

Comment: @MartinJames That being said, if you know another way of dispatching tasks at after a specifci time without a loop, I'm open to suggestions. (I believe there is no other way, or you have ot rely on OS timer API but then I can't use some special features that are not relevant here).

By the way, I have a remote friend who seem to see this problem systematically, but he can't help much on debugging. He have a Windows Vista with a Core 2 Duo. I sent him a version without the sleep, see if it change anything but he will not be able to test it for some time.

Comment: As said the problem could be from different sources. I suspect other piece of code but have no specific clue. So I'm just isolating the bug.

Comment: @Klaim - what I do in similar circumstances is wait on a semaphore, (CreateSemaphore/WaitForSingleObject APIs), with a timeout set to the smallest remaining timeout time of all the items at the head of the queues. If a new timeout-task needs to be added, I push it onto a concurrent 'NewTaskInput' queue and signal the semaphore, so waking up the thread that handles the timeouts 'early'.  It gets the new timeout task and adds it to the appropriate delta/priority queue, re-calculates the smallest remaining timeout time and waits on the semaphore again with the new interval.

Comment: @MartinJames Interesting. But is it possible to do this with cross-platform code? I mean, I don't want to implement myself any semaphore.

Comment: @Klaim: C++11 and Boost have `TimedLockable`.

Comment: @MSalters I don't see the relationship with my case. I can't use waiting functions if there is no way to unwait explicitely.

Comment: @Klaim: Hmm, perhaps you need [`condition_variable::waif_for`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref.condition_variable.wait_for). But turn this into a new question instead of a discussion.

Comment: @MSalters I already use it where necessary but as I don't see how to use it here. With condition variable I have no way to stop waiting when a new task have been pushed in the queue....oh wait I think I see what you mean: I should just use the notification function...will test it ASAP, thanks! I didn't realize this...

Comment: @MSalters I reimplemented the loop using condition_variable::wait_for, so far no difference (or maybe a slight performance loss but I'll need to measure that) so I sent the version to my friend who can easily reproduce the bug. Apparently removing the sleep call altogether does fix the problem, but I don't know if it's the boost implementatino that is buggy or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible that Windows (7 64bit) consider the main thread to be sleeping often and decide that it should sleep for a longer period of time than asked or be definitely ended?

NO.  This does not happen.  MSDN does not indicate that this could happen. Empirically, I have many Windows apps with periodic intervals ranging from ms to hours. The effect you suggest does not happen - it would be disastrous for my apps.

Given the well-known granularity issues with Sleep() calls for very short intervals, a sleeping thread will become ready upon the expiry of the interval.  If there is a CPU core available, (ie. the cores are not all in use running higher-priority threads), the newly-ready thread will become running.

The OS will not extend the interval of Sleep() because of any historical/statistical data associated with the thread states - I don't think it keeps any such data.